# Should I use a surrogate key (id= 1) or natural primary key (tag='sqlalchemy') for my sqlalchemy model?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, primary-key

On the database side, I gather that a natural primary key is preferable as long as it's not prohibitively long, which can cause indexing performance problems.  But as I'm reading through projects that use sqlalchemy via google code search, I almost always find something like:

```
class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'myclass'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

If I have a simple class, like a tag, where I only plan to store one value and require uniqueness anyway, what do I gain through a surrogate primary key, when I'm using sqlalchemy?  One of the SQL books I'm reading suggests ORM's are a legitimate use of the 'antipattern,' but the ORMs he envisions sound more like ActiveRecord or Django.  This comes up a few places in my model, but here's one:

```
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) #should I drop this and add primary_key to Tag.tag?
    tag = Column(Unicode(25), unique=True) 
    ....
```

In my broader, relational model, Tag has multiple many-to-many relationships with other objects.  So there will be a number of intermediate tables that have to store a longer key.  Should I pick tag or id for my primary key?

Comment: I'd personally use natural primary key. OTOH, I'm not expert on sql and cannot properly consider all pros and cons.

Comment: That is my bias too, but using the natural keys seems like such a rare choice in this framework, so I'd like some context as to why that might be, particularly since the framework appears to preserve most of the natural interactions with the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although ORMs or programming languages make some usages easier than others, I think that choosing primary key is a database design problem unrelated to ORM. It is more important to get database schema right on its own grounds. Databases tend to live longer than code that accesses them, anyways.

Search SO (and google) for more general questions on how to chose primary key, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=primary+key+natural+surrogate+database-design ( [Surrogate vs. natural/business keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys), [Relational database design question - Surrogate-key or Natural-key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747730/relational-database-design-question-surrogate-key-or-natural-key), [When not to use surrogate primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714148/when-not-to-use-surrogate-primary-keys), ...)

---

I assume that `Tag` table will not be very large or very dynamic.
In this case *I* would try to use `tag` as a primary key, unless there are important reasons to add some *invisible to end user* primary key, e.g.:

- poor performance under real world data (measured, not imagined),
- frequent changes of tag names (but then, I'd still use some unique string based on first used tag name as key),
- invisible behind-the-scenes merging of tags (but, see previous point),
- problems with different collations -- comparing international data -- in your RDBMS (but, ...)
- ...

---

In general I observed that people tend to err in both directions:

- by using complex multi-field "natural" keys (where particular fields are themselves opaque numbers), when table rows have their own identity and would benefit from having their own surrogate IDs,
- by introducing random numeric codes for everything, instead of using short meaningful strings.

Meaningful primary key values -- if possible -- will prove themselves useful when browsing database by hand. You won't need multiple joins to figure out your data.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, and recognize the great advice, of course.  Your idea of 'erring by avoiding a surrogate key,' as even a possibility in the non-ORM world, is new to me and useful.  And I understand your point is that my ORM doesn't matter.  But I am hoping for an sqlalchemy-specific confirmation of this point, and particularly a better idea of what is gained or lost in that framework (if anything).  Thanks very much for providing such elegant general guidance nonetheless.

Comment: @Profane: I don't advice to avoid surrogate keys. There are plenty of cases when this is the right choice. What I meant is: don't look for what ORM authors find easier to implement (consecutive numbers or GUIDs) but for what is a good database design. Then you will be able to weight arguments that really matter in the long run.

Comment: Yeah I was tracking you, just must not have expressed myself clearly.  Thanks again for the thoughtful input.  I'm accepting your answer because it's the most exhaustive and potentially useful to someone else.  I'll have to keep looking through google code to try to find something I can follow where someone used a natural key with declarative sqlalchemy.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer surrogate keys in most places; The two biggest reasons for this are 1) integer keys are generally smaller/faster and 2) Updating data doesn't require cascades.  That second point is a fairly important one for what you are doing; If there are several many to many tables referencing the tag table, then remember that if someone wants to update a tag (eg, to fix a spelling/case mistake, or to use a more/less specific word, etc), the update will need to be done across all of the tables at the same time.

I'm not saying that you should never use a natural key -- If I am certain that the natural key will never be changed, I will consider a natural key.  Just be certain, otherwise it becomes a pain to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the useful counter-perspective (as opposed to the natural-key advice above).  Perhaps this is the main reason why I see so many of these models with "id" for primary key.  Still hoping someone who understands the inner mechanics of sqlalchemy can give some insight into whether it matters in a framework-specific context.  Thanks again for the input.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I see people (over)using surrogate keys, I remember Roy Hann's blog articles regarding this topic, especially the second and the third article:

- http://community.actian.com/forum/blogs/rhann/127-surrogate-keys-part-2-boring-bit.html
- http://community.actian.com/forum/blogs/rhann/128-surrogate-keys-part-3-surrogates-composites.html

I strongly suggest people reading them as these articles come from a person who has spent few decades as database expert.

Nowadays surrogate key usage reminds me of early years of the 21 century when people used XML for literally everything, both where it did belong, and where it did not belong.

Comment: Unfortunately the links you posted are no longer valid. I did some cursory googling but had no luck. Do you happen to have updated links to these articles? Thanks!